# Spring MVC and AOP: @Pointcuts only apply for Rest Controllers and not for common Web Controllers

Tags: spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I am working with `Spring Framework` 4.3.3 in a web environment.

I have a `@Controller` used for `Web` requests through a `Web Browser` that uses how dependency other `@Controller` but for `Rest` purposes. It latter mentioned uses a `@Service` etc...

This approach about a 'Web' using a 'Rest' how a dependency is explained in [Content Negotiation using Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) for the `Combining Data and Presentation Formats` section. Until here for development/testing and production works fine. It is a valuable approach.

**Note** The `Rest` class is annotated with `@Controller` because I work with `ResponseEntity<?>` and `@ResponseBody`.

The problem is with `AOP`

About its infrastructure I have:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AopConfig {

}
```

About the `@Controller`s I have these two classes:

- `PersonaDeleteOneController` with:

  - `deleteOne(@PathVariable String id, Model model)` for `@GetMapping`
  - `deleteOne(@PathVariable String id, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)` for `@DeleteMapping`
- `PersonaRestController`

  - `deleteOne(@PathVariable String id)` for `@DeleteMapping`

These two classes are declared within the same package named:

- `com.manuel.jordan.controller.persona`

I have the following `@Pointcut`:

```
@Pointcut(value=
"execution(* com.manuel.jordan.controller.*.*Controller.deleteOne(String, ..)) 
&& args(id) && target(object)")
public void deleteOnePointcut(String id, Object object){}
```

That `@Pointcut` is used for the following advice:

```
@Before(value="ControllerPointcut.deleteOnePointcut(id, object)")
public void beforeAdviceDeleteOne(String id, Object object){
    logger.info("beforeAdviceDeleteOne - @Controller: {} - Method: deleteOne - id: {}", object.getClass().getSimpleName(), id);
}
```

When I execute the `Rest` tests I can confirm through `AOP + logging` that prints the following pattern:

- `@Controller` (*Rest*) -> `@Service` -> `@Repository`

Until here all work how is expected

When I execute the `Web` tests I can confirm through `AOP + logging` that prints the following pattern:

- `@Controller` (*Rest*) -> `@Service` -> `@Repository`

What I need or expect is the following:

- `@Controller` (*Web*) -> `@Controller` (*Rest*) -> `@Service` -> `@Repository`

What is wrong or missing?. The `deleteOne` signatures are not ambiguous about their parameters.

Same case for Production.

**Alpha**

Here the controllers:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/personas")
public class PersonaDeleteOneController {

    private final PersonaRestController personaRestController;

    @Autowired
    public PersonaDeleteOneController(PersonaRestController personaRestController){
        this.personaRestController = personaRestController;
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/delete/{id}",
                produces=MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String deleteOne(@PathVariable String id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute(personaRestController.findOneById(id));
        model.addAttribute("root", "/personas/delete");
        return "persona/deleteOne";
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value="/delete/{id}",
                   produces=MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String deleteOne(@PathVariable String id, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        personaRestController.deleteOne(id);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "process.successful");
        return "redirect:/message";
    }

}
```

And

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/personas")
public class PersonaRestController {

    private final PersonaService personaService;

    @Autowired
    public PersonaRestController(PersonaService personaService){
        this.personaService = personaService;
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value="/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteOne(@PathVariable String id){
        personaService.deleteOne(id);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

    ....
```

How you can see I don't use `this.` to execute the method invocations.

Comment: Can you provide code examples with `@Controller` class method invocations? The problem can be if you try to do things like `this.deleteOne(...)`.

Comment: Done, please see the `Alpha` section. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the problem is in you `pointcut` definition. You may notice that your advice method is performed only for methods with one parameter, so this is due to the fact that you have specified `args(id)` in the pointcut declaration. It must work as you expect if you remove `args(id)`, but in this case some workaround must be used to expose parameter value.

I think that this is strange behavior form AspectJ because constructions like `execution(* *.*(String, ..)) && args(arg) && target(t))` has clear semantic sense to capture all the methods with `String` first parameter and expose it to `args`. It can be a bug or feature, at least, to AspectJ developers.

To get what you want, you can use a workaround with `joinPoint.getArgs()` inside advice method like this:

```
@Pointcut(value=
"execution(* com.manuel.jordan.controller.*.*Controller.deleteOne(..)) && target(object)")
public void deleteOnePointcut(Object object){}

@Before(value="ControllerPointcut.deleteOnePointcut(object)")
public void beforeAdviceDeleteOne(JoinPoint jp, Object object){
    Object id = jp.getArgs()[0];
    logger.info("beforeAdviceDeleteOne - @Controller: {} - Method: deleteOne - id: {}", object.getClass().getSimpleName(), id);
}
```

Comment: Works. Thanks so much. This is a `funny` or `tricky` case. I hope some `AspectJ` developer read this post. And if it is really a bug then an issue should be raised.

Comment: BTW for other `@Pointcut` for other expression (not for this case) containing `(String, ..)` I can have `args(id, ..)`. I thought was not possible use `..` within the `args()` section.